# ¿Cómo llenar un DataTable con una consulta personalizada?

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, datatables

Quiero llenar un DataTable con una consulta, donde se considere como filtros de fechas los siguientes inputs:

```
<input type="date" name="fecha_inicio" id="fecha_inicio">
<input type="date" name=" fecha_final" id="fecha_final">
```

Los cuales tienen el formato `Y-m-d`. No sé si se podrá de lado servidor para llenar la tabla personalizada.

```
function listar(){
    var table = $("#dataServicio").DataTable({
        "destroy":true,
        "scrollX": true,
        "order": [ 0, 'desc' ],
       "ajax":{
            "method":"POST",
            "url":"ajax/servicios_listar.php"
        },
        "columns":[
            {"data":"id_prod"},
            {"data":"nombre_cat"},
            {"data":"fecha"},
            {"data":"descripcion_p"}
          ]           
    });
}
```

El archivo `servicios_listar.php` contiene:

```
require ("../config/conexion.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM servicios, catservicios   WHERE estado_p = 1 AND tipo_p=id_cat ";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conectahugo, $sql);

//si no hay reultado imprimimos que diga error 
if (!$resultado) {
    die('Error no hay datos');
}else{
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        $arreglo["data"][]=$data;            
    }
//pasamos los datos json
    echo json_encode($arreglo);
}

mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conectahugo);
```

Comment: ¿Consulta que se encuentra en los inputs?¿Buscar en la tabla? ¿Quieres enviar los valores de tus inputs como parámetros de tu petición por POST?

Comment: quiero que llene con un rango de fecha inicio y fin para que genere un reporte. los inputs llevan fechas. Y-m-d. tu sabes como llenarla para que delado del cliente seleccione la fecha de resultados que se desea ver, Bendiciones.

Comment: ¿Quieres que desde lado del servidor filtrar con el rango de fecha tu lista que traes con `servicios_listar.php`? ¿Quieres recuperar la fecha inicio y fin en el `$_REQUEST` cuando llamas a `servicios_listar.php`?

Comment: te cuento que esto es nuevo para mi y he visto que se puede trabajar del lado del servidor, pero no se como hacer esto? que me propones como para como resolverlo.

Comment: `code       "dataSrc": " " `   tu sabes algo de esto? he visto que lo utilizan para algo así

Comment: Claro, puedes filtrar de lado cliente o servidor. Del lado cliente, podrías usar `dataSrc`, y en base a la lista que obtiene de tu petición filtrar con los rangos de fecha. El problema es que te traes toda la información para luego filtrarla. Del lado servidor, al momento de hacer tu petición puedes recuperar los valores de tu rango de fecha en el `$_REQUEST` y puedes filtrar ahí la información, por ejemplo puedes enviar las fechas como parámetro de tu consulta a una base de datos. Lo recomendable es hacerlo del lado servidor.

Comment: @Davilo si quiero enviar las fechas como parametro del lado del servidor. Me puedes dar un ejemplo de como hacerlo.=)

Comment: este es el listar_servicios que llama el ajax `code   require ("../config/conexion.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM servicios, catservicios   WHERE estado_p = 1 ` PREGUNTO DEBO  EDITAR ESTO TAMBIEN.?

Comment: Podrías [edit] tu pregunta e incluir el código de tu comentario, asimismo, indicar el formato de fechas que usas.

Comment: ya lo edite espero que se util

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para enviar el rango de fechas como parámetro en tu petición POST, podrías considerar:

```
var table = $("#dataServicio").DataTable({
        "destroy": true,
        "scrollX": true,
        "order": [0, 'desc'],
        "ajax": {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "ajax/servicios_listar.php",
            "data": function (d) {
                return $.extend({}, d, {
                    "fecha_inicio": $('#fecha_inicio').val(),
                    "fecha_final": $('#fecha_final').val()
                });
            }
        },
        "columns": [{
                "data": "id_prod"
            }, {
                "data": "nombre_cat"
            }, {
                "data": "fecha"
            }, {
                "data": "descripcion_p"
            }
        ],

    });
```

Ya en tu archivo PHP, podrías considerar:

```
require ("../config/conexion.php");

$fecha_inicio = $_REQUEST["fecha_inicio"];
$fecha_fin = $_REQUEST["fecha_fin"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM servicios, catservicios WHERE estado_p = 1 AND tipo_p=id_cat AND fecha BETWEEN '".$fecha_inicio."' AND '".$fecha_fin."'"; 
$resultado = mysqli_query($conectahugo, $sql); 
//si no hay reultado imprimimos que diga error 
if (!$resultado) { 
    die('Error no hay datos'); 
}
else{ 
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) { 
        $arreglo["data"][]=$data; 
    }

    //pasamos los datos json echo   
    echo json_encode($arreglo); 
} 

mysqli_free_result($resultado); 
mysqli_close($conectahugo);
```

Donde, `fecha` es la columna donde se considera el rango de fechas.

---

**Referencia:**

- [ajax.data](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data): Agrega o modifica datos enviados al servidor con una solicitud de Ajax.

Comment: ok lo probare y doy  100 dame chance

Comment: GRACIAS MUCHAS GRACIAS QUE DIOS TE BENDIGA. DONDE APRENDISTE ESTO `code "data": function (d) {
                return $.extend({}, d, {
                    "fecha_inicio": $('#fecha_inicio').val(),
                    "fecha_final": $('#fecha_final').val()
                }); `

Comment: @Carlos acabo de agregar la referencia

Comment: Gracias y SIEMPRE BENDICIONES. =)

Comment: Al amigo Davlio que respondio, GRACIAS! a mi tambien me ha servido, busque por varios dias en la red, me di topes con el codigo y no lograba pasarle los parametros, aun en la pagina oficial de DATATABLES el codigo que mostraban no pasaba los parametros. Amigo GRACIAS!!!!!!!